# PHP echo with three levels of nested quotes

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-livewire

I want to execute the following echo:

```
echo '<div class="grid grid-cols-1 mt-4">
    @foreach( $sectionOneCompare as $chart )
        <livewire:is :component="$chart['type']">
    @endforeach
</div>'
```

You'll notice the three levels of quotation nesting... this is what's stumping me. There's a million questions already asked about this, and they all say to escape like so:

```
echo "<div class=\"grid grid-cols-1 mt-4\">
    @foreach( $sectionOneCompare as $chart )
        <livewire:is :component=\"$chart['type']\">
    @endforeach
</div>"
```

...but it does not work for me. Both ways, [it fails to parse properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbTXS.png). How do I nest this correctly?

**Edit:** I left out of my original question that this echo is inside a PHP if statement:

```
<?php if ($sectionOne != null) {
  // above code snippet
} ?>
```

Since I'm using Blade/Livewire, the answer ended up being to use a Blade conditional instead. That way I didn't have to nest quotes at all! Thanks to Qirel's comment for helping me realize this.

```
@if ($sectionOne != null) 
  // above code snippet
@endif
```

Comment: I don’t use Laravel at all, however I assume `@` syntax is template-only, and unless you are doing an equivalent of `eval` that won’t work. My guess is to either use a PHP-native `for` loop server-side, or use normal template syntax in your template code.

Comment: You can't use `echo` to print Livewire, as that's rendered in Blade (the template). Why do you want to echo it with native PHP in the first place?

Comment: @Qirel You forced me to solve my own problem with that last question. I've edited the question to update, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I dont know livewire, but I think that what you want is this

```php
echo '<div class="grid grid-cols-1 mt-4">';
    @foreach( $sectionOneCompare as $chart )
        <livewire:is :component="$chart['type']">
    @endforeach
echo '</div>';
```